# how to properly add inner join condition to layered filter query?

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, sql

I need to add inner join condition in layered navigation filter basic query line this:

```
    SELECT `e`.*,
           `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`,
           `price_index`.`price`,
           `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
           `price_index`.`final_price`,
           IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`,
           `price_index`.`min_price`,
           `price_index`.`max_price`,
           `price_index`.`tier_price`
    FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id
    AND cat_index.store_id=3
    AND cat_index.visibility IN (2,
                                 4)
    AND cat_index.category_id = '3'
    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id
    AND price_index.website_id = '1'
    AND price_index.customer_group_id = '4';
```

It is required to get only products which are exist in `custom_translation` in field `product_id` table for certain `language_id`, but when i add these inner join statement to query to as above like this :

```
    "query_as_above" INNER JOIN `custom_translation` as `t` ON t.product_id=e.entity_id
    AND t.language_id = 35;
```

I get empty results, althrought I have correspoding

```
    mysql> select language_id, product_id, name from custom_translation limit 1;
    +-------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
    | language_id | product_id | name                              |
    +-------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
    |          35 |         55 | German product virtual            |
    +-------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
```

and

```
    mysql> select * from catalog_product_entity where entity_id=55;
    +-----------+----------------+------------------+---------+----------------------------------+-------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
    | entity_id | entity_type_id | attribute_set_id | type_id | sku                              | has_options | required_options | created_at          | updated_at          |
    +-----------+----------------+------------------+---------+----------------------------------+-------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
    |        55 |              4 |                4 | virtual | 5a310fed97af665e5576796e69a58f8d |           1 |                0 | 2016-02-17 13:59:31 | 2016-02-18 23:36:40 |
    +-----------+----------------+------------------+---------+----------------------------------+-------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Why my statment fails and How to craft the inner join condition properly ?
In result I would love the have something like:

```
    "layered_filter_query" INNER JOIN `custom_translation` as `t` ON t.product_id=e.entity_id
    AND t.language_id  IN (25, 36, 55);
```

To get all products for which there are entries in table `custom_translation` for certain `language_id`'s

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

solved with subquery

```
 "query_as_above" WHERE ( SELECT e.entity_id in (SELECT translation.product_id 
                                            FROM custom_translation 
                                            AS translation 
                                            WHERE translation.language_id 
                                            IN (25, 36, 55)))
```